# How can I get the app store link to upgrade my app (iphone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to prompt the user (once, I record it) to upgrade the iphone app if it is out of date.  I've found a few sites that explain how to get the link to your app in the app store once it is already there.  [Here's one for example](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-launch-app-store-from-my-iphone-application/).

The problem is, all these guides require the app to be in the store before you can get the ID to link to it.  This is a new app.  Is it impossible to figure out what your app ID (and link) will be before submitting your code?  Therefor it is impossible for your first version to have an upgrade link embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to http://itunes.com/app/App_Name, if your app's name is unique.

Your other option would be to fetch the update notice with an HTTP request instead of building the wording into the app. That'd let you present any message with wording you could determine on your web server, not in the code itself.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to mix it into an API request.  Not so much for the wording, but there are some scenarios that force you to create a new app ID.  This way, we could prompt the user to upgrade across app IDs.  Thanks ceejay.

Comment: Regarding your answer though, does that work in-app?  The material I've read says that a phobos. prefix is required.  Is that not the case?

Comment: The http link redirects to a URL that should trigger the app store.

Comment: Ah, cool yeah that will work for a backup url.  It's a little crappy that it has to launch safari, but I can't find an alternative that doesn't.  Thanks.